# Why does lapack dtrmm.f seem to not work properly?

Tags: fortran, lapack

I decided to use lapack subroutine [`dtrmm`](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/lapack-3.1.1/html/dtrmm.f.html) instead of `matmul` to multiply lower triangular (d,d) matrix and general (d,n) matrix. However, it doesn't seem to work correctly. The following code compares results of `matlum` (top) and `dtrmm`

```
Program test
    implicit none
    integer, parameter :: n = 3, d = 3 ! arbitrary numbers, no luck with other values
    integer :: i
    real(8) :: a(d,d), b(d,n), c(d,n)

    call random_number(a)
    call random_number(b)
    do i=2,d
        a(1:i-1,i) = 0
    end do
    c = matmul(a,b)
    call dtrmm('L','L','N','N',d,n,1,a,d,b,d) ! documentation linked in the question
    print*, 'correct result : '
    do i=1,d
        print*, c(i,:)
    end do
    print*, 'dtrmm yields : '
    do i=1,d
        print*, b(i,:)
    end do

End Program test
```

returns this

```
 correct result : 
  0.75678922130735249       0.51830058846965921       0.51177304237548271     
   1.1974740765385026       0.46115246753697681       0.98237114765741340     
  0.98027798241945430       0.53718796235743815        1.0328498570683342     
 dtrmm yields : 
   6.7262070844500211E+252   4.6065628207770121E+252   4.5485471599475983E+252
   1.0642935166471391E+253   4.0986405551607272E+252   8.7311388520015068E+252
   8.7125351741793473E+252   4.7744304178222945E+252   9.1797845822711462E+252
```

Other lapack suboutines I used work fine. What could be causing this to misbehave? Is this a bug, or have I just badly misunderstood something?

Comment: `1` is an integer literal constant, not the double precision that is expected for the argument `alpha`.

Comment: Note dtrmm is part of BLAS, not LAPACK. And real(8) is not portable - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/838310/fortran-90-kind-parameter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a simple data type error. The factor `alpha` must be of type double precision whereas you supplied an integer of default kind.

Thus

```
...
! call dtrmm('L','L','N','N',d,n,1,a,d,b,d)  WRONG
call dtrmm('L','L','N','N',d,n,1d0,a,d,b,d)  ! note 1d0 instead of 1
...
```

gives the correct result.